# Where is the NPC for doing proving grounds in the Dreamgrove?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

i spend quite some time looking for this NPC but haven't found it... i also searched for maps of the Dreamgrove to check if it's marked on there, but to no avail.

Comment: Never played WoW, but everything I'm finding in google is pointing to [Trial Master Rotun](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=72536/trial-master-rotun) who can be found in Kun-Lai Summit.

Comment: @TimmyJim that's not the only one. ;)

Comment: And that's why I don't play WoW :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically every class trainer + the guy at the mission table in the WoD garrison sends you there (and the panda guy from MoP at the Temple of the White Tiger).

In Legion you'll find class trainers in some class halls. But the Dreamgrove is one of them without a trainer, so there is no way to get to the Proving Grounds directly from there.  Shamans for example would have one.

Comment: I found the DK one but i don´t see one in the warlock hall.

Answer (score 1):

In Legion you will find class trainers by the portals in Dalaran (Broken Shores). Most classes are there, but not mages, DKs, or Demon Hunters.